# Как программно поместить ConstraintLayout из layout.xml в другой контейнер?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Имеется некий layout в котором имеется ConstraintLayout и вложенные элементы. Собственно вопрос в том, как программно у данного layout поместить ConstraintLayout в другой контейнер типа (LinearLayout, relativeLayout) ?

Comment: `val view = ...; view.parent.removeView(view); anotherView.addView(view);`?

Comment: ЮрийСПб, так у view.parent нет метода removeView

Comment: Надо  `view.parent` скастовать к `ViewGroup` https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220349/3212712